# Parentheses after FROM in MYSQL, strange synthax

Tags: mysql

I have one table "FRIENDS" with columns "id", "toid", "fromid".
I have found this weird synthax (for me) query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(friends.myfrndids) myfrndids
  FROM ( SELECT toid AS myfrndids FROM `friends`
          WHERE status = 1 AND fromid = '231'
          UNION
         SELECT fromid AS myfrndids FROM `friends`
          WHERE status = 1 AND toid = '231'
       ) friends;
```

What is strange to me are the parentheses after the first FROM: `` FROM (SELECT toid AS myfrndids FROM `friends` WHERE status = 1 AND fromid = '231' UNION SELECT fromid AS myfrndids FROM `friends` WHERE status = 1 AND toid = '231') friends ``

I have always found: `` FROM `table` ``

Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html). You can select [from](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html) the results of the subquery. In short it looks like this:

```
SELECT `field` FROM (subquery) AS tbl;
```

Where the subquery is just a regular sql query, like `SELECT field from table`

Answer (score 0):

The part that is expected after the `FROM` clause is a table! but its doesn't need to always be a named table. You can also build a table on the flay and then select from it! The result of the sub query is a table and you are then selecting from it!

```
(SELECT toid as myfrndids FROM 'friends' WHERE status =1 and fromid = '231' union SELECT fromid as myfrndids FROM 'friends' WHERE status =1 and toid = '231')
```

returns a table and then `friends` after that gives an alias (temporary nick name) so that u can refer it later in the WHERE clause or so.

I hope this helps